# define a variable to in XSLT that should be set to true when there are duplicates in the XML

Tags: xslt

I am having the following XML and XSLT code, I am trying to set the $hasDuplicateAllowance to true when the allowance section is deleted and added again without any changes. can anyone help me in identifying why the variable is not set to true when the allowance details are matching.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stack>    
    <Stack1>        
        <W1>
            <Worker_Summary>
                <WID>1234</WID>
                <Employee_ID>1234</Employee_ID>
            </Worker_Summary>
            <Effective_Change Sequence="0">
                <Derived_Event_Code>DTA</Derived_Event_Code>
                <Effective_Moment>2023-03-13T00:00:00.000-07:00</Effective_Moment>
                <Entry_Moment>2023-08-09T06:51:59.232-07:00</Entry_Moment>                
                <Comp_plan isUpdated="1">
                    <Allowance_Plan isDeleted="1">
                        <Compensation_Plan>2780</Compensation_Plan>
                        <Amount>123</Amount>
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Frequency>OTHER</Frequency>
                        <Start_Date>13032023</Start_Date>
                        <End_Date isDeleted="1">30042023</End_Date>
                        <Compensation_Element>allowance_name</Compensation_Element>
                    </Allowance_Plan>
                    <Allowance_Plan isAdded="1">
                        <Compensation_Plan>2780</Compensation_Plan>
                        <Amount>123</Amount>
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Frequency>OTHER</Frequency>
                        <Start_Date>13032023</Start_Date>
                        <End_Date>30042023</End_Date>
                        <Compensation_Element>allowance_name</Compensation_Element>
                    </Allowance_Plan>
                </Comp_plan>
                <Additional_Information>
                    <WorkerID>1234</WorkerID>
                </Additional_Information>
            </Effective_Change>            
        </W1>
    </Stack1>    
</Stack>
```

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

```
<!-- Define a key to match Allowance_Plan elements based on specified criteria -->
<xsl:key name="allowance-key" match="//Allowance_Plan" use="concat(Compensation_Plan, '|', Start_Date, '|', End_Date, '|', Amount, '|', Compensation_Element)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Define a variable to store the result of the condition -->
    <xsl:variable name="hasDuplicateAllowance">
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Check if there are multiple Allowance_Plan elements with the same criteria -->
            <xsl:when test="count(//Allowance_Plan[isDeleted='1' and isAdded='1'][count(. | key('allowance-key', concat(Compensation_Plan, '|', Start_Date, '|', End_Date, '|', Amount, '|', Compensation_Element))[1]) = 1]) > 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'false'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <!-- Output the value of the variable -->
    <Result>
        <HasDuplicateAllowance>
            <xsl:value-of select="$hasDuplicateAllowance"/>
        </HasDuplicateAllowance>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues. The most problematic one seems to be the method you use to detect the presence of duplicates.

Consider the following simplified example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="allowance-key" match="Allowance_Plan" use="concat(Compensation_Plan, '|', Start_Date, '|', End_Date, '|', Amount, '|', Compensation_Element)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="duplicates" select="//Allowance_Plan[count(key('allowance-key', concat(Compensation_Plan, '|', Start_Date, '|', End_Date, '|', Amount, '|', Compensation_Element))) > 1]"/>
    <Result>
        <HasDuplicateAllowance>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($duplicates)"/>
         </HasDuplicateAllowance>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have left out the `[isDeleted='1' and isAdded='1']` part of your attempt, because:

1. `isDeleted` and `isAdded` are attributes, so they need to be addressed as  `[@isDeleted='1' and @isAdded='1']`;
2. There is no `Allowance_Plan` in your example that meets the condition of having both.

---

### Added:

Upon reread, I see that you want to detect duplicate pairs where one `Allowance_Plan` was added and other deleted. This could be done as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="deleted" match="Allowance_Plan[@isDeleted='1']" use="concat(Compensation_Plan, '|', Start_Date, '|', End_Date, '|', Amount, '|', Compensation_Element)"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="duplicates" select="//Allowance_Plan[@isAdded='1' and key('deleted', concat(Compensation_Plan, '|', Start_Date, '|', End_Date, '|', Amount, '|', Compensation_Element))]"/>
    <Result>
        <HasDuplicateAllowance>
            <xsl:value-of select="boolean($duplicates)"/>
         </HasDuplicateAllowance>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `isAdded` and `isDeleted` are attributes, not child elements, so you need to refer to them as `@isAdded` and `@isDeleted`.

Secondly, you are not interested in whether there is a single `Allowance_Plan` element that has both attributes, you are interested (I think) in whether there are two elements, both identical except that one has `@isAdded='1'` and the other has `@isDeleted='1'`.

As so often happens, you've stated the requirement by reference to a single example, and it's always hard to generalise from one example to infer the complete specification. However, the solution might be something like:

```
<xsl:when test="Comp_plan[Allowance_Plan[1]/@isDeleted='1' 
  and Allowance_Plan[2]/@isAdded='1' 
  and deep-equal(Allowance_Plan[1]/*, Allowance_Plan[2]/*)">
```

If I remember right, the `deep-equal()` function requires XSLT 2.0 or later: you didn't tag your question with a specific XSLT version. In 1.0 you would probably want to add a long list of conditions comparing individual child elements pairwise.